# Error al ejecutar el procedimiento con cursores

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-cursores, mysqlprocedure

Crea un ***procedimiento*** que inserte sólo los alumnos de informática en la tabla ***ALUMNOSINF***, teniendo en cuenta la estructura de esta tabla.

***Por ejemplo :***

> Debe tener en cuenta que el atributo ***nombre_apellidos*** resulta de la concatenación de los atributos ***nombre y apellidos.*** Antes de la inserción de cada tupla en la tabla ***ALUMNOSINF*** debe mostrar por pantalla ***el nombre y el apellido*** que va a insertar. ***Utiliza cursores.***

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists ejer1;//
create procedure ejer1()
    begin
        declare VidMatricula integer(4);
        declare Vnombre_apellido varchar(50);
        declare Vprecio decimal(6,2);
        declare fin int default 0;
        
        declare curejer1 cursor  for
            select numMatricula,concat(nombre," ",apellidos), precioMatricula
            from Alumnos;
            
        declare continue handler for not found set fin=1;
        
        open curEjer1;
        select * from AlumnosInf;
        
        bucle: loop
            fetch curEjer1 into VidMatricula,  Vnombre_apellido, Vprecio
        if fin=1 then
            leave bucle;
            end if;
            insert into AlumnosInf values (
                 VidMatricula,  Vnombre_apellido, Vprecio
            )
        
        end loop;
        end;
//
```

Comment: Ya te lo he solucionado, Avisa si funciona

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Muchas Gracias ya me funciona.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido mi respuesta @Rosa, pero para que se resuelva la preguntas debes marcas con el ✔ la respuesta que mas te ha ayudado y si es buena de votarla positivamente con ^ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solución :***

***1.*** Te falta varios `;`

***2.*** Te faltara un `FETCH`.

***3.*** La variable ***fin*** la he cambiado por ***boolean***.

***4.*** Tu bucle lo sustituido por un `WHILE`.

***5.*** Tu `SELECT * FROM ...` esta mal porque deberias llamar a la variable `SELECT Vnombre_apellido;`

***6.*** Te faltaba un `DELIMITER` y aunque no este mal usar `//` es mejor `$$` da menos problemas.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ejer1 $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ejer1()
BEGIN
    DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
    DECLARE VidMatricula INT;
    DECLARE Vnombre_apellido VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE Vprecio FLOAT(6,2);    
    DECLARE curejer1 CURSOR FOR SELECT numMatricula,concat(nombre," ",apellidos), 
    precioMatricula FROM Alumnos;        
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=1;
    OPEN curEjer1;
    FETCH curEjer1 INTO VidMatricula, Vnombre_apellido, Vprecio;   
    WHILE fin = FALSE DO
        SELECT Vnombre_apellido;
        FETCH curEjer1 INTO VidMatricula, Vnombre_apellido, Vprecio;
        INSERT INTO AlumnosInf VALUES(VidMatricula,  Vnombre_apellido, Vprecio);
    END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```